# Automatic JSDoc style comments with last modified time in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

In Sublime text there was some option or maybe plugin that allowed you to put at the top of the file:

```
/**
 *@Last Modified Time: 
 */
```

and it would add the actual time in there whenever you saved the file

very useful

How to get the same feature in vscode?